# Waiting Web Browser Document Complete Without Leaving The Method

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control

I want to wait for the webbrowser to complete loading the page and do something after; However i do not want to leave the main method because i will return a bool depending on the the value read for the browser page.

Here is what i tried but obviously i am leaving the main method

```
    public async Task<bool> Commit()
    {
        try
        {
            Browser = new WebBrowser { ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true };

            Browser.Navigate(Server);
            Browser.DocumentCompleted += DocumentCompleteMethod;

//HERE I WANNA RETURN TRUE,FALSE DEPENDING ON THE VALUE I WILL READ FROM THE WEB PAGE
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

private void DocumentCompleteMethod(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{

}
```

Comment: DocumentCompleted doesn't happen in your commit method .. you merely wire up the event to be handled by another. And you can only access data from the document in the documentCompleteMethod .. you need to rethink your approach.

Comment: so can you provide me with another way i achieve what i want ? i want to call a returnable method that replays me with true,false depending on what it found in the webpage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could modify your code to this.

```
  public async Task<bool> Commit()
        {
            try
            {
                var Browser = new WebBrowser { ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true };

                Browser.Navigate(Server);
                Browser.DocumentCompleted += DocumentCompleteMethod;

               while (Browser.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete) { Application.DoEvents(); }

   //At this point you can access the document as it is sure to be loaded.
   string title = Browser.Document.Title;

    //HERE I WANNA RETURN TRUE,FALSE DEPENDING ON THE VALUE I WILL READ FROM THE WEB PAGE
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

    private void DocumentCompleteMethod(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Comment: you mean that i am no longer in need to register the DocumentCompleteMethod right ?

Comment: You can leave it empty since you no longer need to access any of the event arguments there.

Answer (score 2):

This is a common issue with async programming.  Your normal synchronous processes don't work like you would wish.

Consider re-architecting your process using async methodologies.. don't return a value, kick off a process and let the process handle the action to be taken.  For example, let the `DocumentCompleteMethod` take action depending on the results of the page.

If you truly must force an async process to conform to synchronous methods, then consider using thread synchronizers like `AutoResetEvent`.  Jon Skeet posted a great answer to a question here on StackOverflow regarding executing a WebBrowser.Navigate method in a thread.

Comment: could you provide me with a link or something to the topic you are pointing to, because what i want to achieve must be done the way i am describing... i cant handle things in the document complete.

Comment: Use your search-fu.  I gave you enough information to go on.  I'd run the same search you would to find the information.

Answer (score 1):

I created this class today, with the help of another post on stackoverflow, I want to get the ready webbrowser control without any thread blocking using (Async/Await).

```
Dim bb = New wbBrowser
Dim wb = Await bb.GetBrowserAsync("http://www.msn.com")
```

Here is the class:

```
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.Threading.Tasks

Public Class wbBrowser
    Implements IDisposable

    Dim m_wbBrowser As New WebBrowser
    Dim m_tcs As TaskCompletionSource(Of WebBrowser)

    Public Sub New()
        m_wbBrowser.ScrollBarsEnabled = False
        m_wbBrowser.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = False
        AddHandler m_wbBrowser.DocumentCompleted, Sub(s, args) m_tcs.SetResult(m_wbBrowser)
    End Sub

    Public Async Function GetBrowserAsync(ByVal URL As String) As Task(Of WebBrowser)
        m_wbBrowser.Navigate(URL)
        Return Await WhenDocumentCompleted(m_wbBrowser)
    End Function

    Private Function WhenDocumentCompleted(browser As WebBrowser) As Task(Of WebBrowser)
        m_tcs = New TaskCompletionSource(Of WebBrowser)
        Return m_tcs.Task
    End Function

    Private disposedValue As Boolean
    Protected Overridable Sub Dispose(disposing As Boolean)
        If Not Me.disposedValue Then
            If disposing Then
                m_wbBrowser.Dispose()
            End If
        End If
        Me.disposedValue = True
    End Sub
    Public Sub Dispose() Implements IDisposable.Dispose
        Dispose(True)
        GC.SuppressFinalize(Me)
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Don't forget to do `RemoveHandler`, or you'll have an exception for multiple navigations.