# How to a wait untill delegate evente done?

Tags: c#

how to waiting until delegate method is  finished

```
  await webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += delegate
            {

                //finished 
            }; 

        //when finished do some things
```

so how to do that

Thanks

Comment: That line of code doesn't execute `DocumentCompleted`. It registers the delegate as an event handler for the event `DocumentCompleted`.

Comment: Look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14864891/waiting-web-browser-document-complete-without-leaving-the-method

Comment: as @John said, your event will not run, it's just a registration.

Comment: That code runs on the UI thread, you cannot wait.  Trying to wait causes deadlock, the DocumentCompleted event cannot fire.  Simply move any code you now have after this line of code into the event handler.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I propose you to use this solution which could in my opinion meet your needs .

***WebBrowser class :***

```
class WebBrowser
{
    public event EventHandler DocumentCompleted;
    public async Task RaiseEvent(object o,EventArgs e )
    {
         DocumentCompleted(o, e);
    }
}
```

***How you Could Raise your Event :***

```
WebBrowser w = new WebBrowser();

w.DocumentCompleted += delegate (object o, EventArgs e)
{
   var result = " hello event ";
};
//this part invoke all the delegates or method registered to this event .
await w.RaiseEvent(this, New EventArgs());
```

Answer (score -1):

You should invoke it instead. Invoke blocks until the delegate returns I believe.

```
Invoke((webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted)delegate
{
    //Your code here
); 

//This will run after 'Your code here'
```

Comment: Not sensible, the event is raised by WebBrowser.

Comment: I do not think your proposal answers the question